# Validate Field Type Date with package `validate`

Tags: r, validation

I would like to test my data.frame using the `validate` package. I have some Date columns in the data frame. How do I check that the column is in the right format?

I tried so far

```
library(validate)
dat <- data.frame(
    when=seq(as.Date(Sys.time()), length.out=5, by="1 day"),
    value=runif(5)  
)
rules <- validator(
    "when" %in% names(.),
    inherits(when, "POSIXct"), # does not work: "Invalid syntax detected"
    "value" %in% names(.),
    is.numeric(value)
)
confront(dat, rules)
```

but this results in a warning that the second rule is ignored due to invalid syntax.

EDIT:
I tried

```
is_date <- function(...) is(..., "Date")
rules <- validator(
    inherits(when, "POSIXct"), 
    is(when, "Date"),
    is_date(when)
)
```

and all attempts lead to errors "invalid syntax".

Maybe `validator()` is not intended to do column type checks?

Comment: To check values, see section 2.7 of [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/vignettes/cookbook.html).  To check column type, `is(dat$when, "Date")`.

Comment: I still cannot get it going, please see the edited question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
library(lubridate)

rules1 <- validator(
  is.numeric(value),
  !is.na(when),       # Check value validity
  is.Date(when)       # Check column type
)

summary(confront(dat, rules1))
  name items passes fails nNA error warning        expression
1   V1     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE is.numeric(value)
2   V2     5      5     0   0 FALSE   FALSE      !is.na(when)
3   V3     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE     is.Date(when)
```

If you don't want to use `lubridate`, try

```
is.Date.column <- function(x) inherits(x, "Date")

rules2 <- validator(
  is.numeric(value),
  !is.na(when),
  is.Date.column(when)
)
summary(confront(dat, rules2))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. It seems the name of the function is important. `is.Date.column` works, `is_Date_column` (with the same definition) does not.

Comment: Glad to have helped.  From the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validate/vignettes/cookbook.html), "In `validate`, any function starting with`is.` (‘is’ followed by a dot) is considered a validation function".